Is it possible to configure Chrome OS to drag and resize windows with alt-mouse, similar to Linux?
Most Linux window systems come with a nice feature: you can move and resize application windows by holding Alt and dragging the window with either left or right mouse button (see e.g. How to enable dragging windows with alt-click in gnome 3 / gnome shell).
I know there are tools which allow the same style window management for Windows (e.g. Use ALT to move windows in Windows like in Linux) and Mac OS (e.g. Alt+click-drag window resizing on a Mac? (Similar to X-Windows)).
But I haven't found a way to get the same on a ChromeOS / Chromebook.
Do we have a way to configure Chrome OS / Chromebook to allow holding a keyboard button (e.g. alt) and dragging mouse to move and resize windows?
